# Как получить данные из onResponse? Retrofit.

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Не могу получить данные из onResponse.

```
    public void loadData() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(myurl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RESTPK service = retrofit.create(RESTPK.class);
    Call<JsonStr> call = service.loadJsonStr();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonStr>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonStr> call, Response<JsonStr> response) {
            pathPoster = response.body().getPath().get(0).get1(); //переменая которую мне нужно вытащить
            System.out.println(pathPoster);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonStr> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

Если в onResponse вывести на экран переменную pathPoster, то она показывает правильный результат, но если ее вывести на экран после вызова loadData(), то в ней уже ничего нет и приложение вылетает с ошибкой. Получить данные получил, но пользоваться ими не получается.

```
    loadData();
    System.out.println(pathPoster);
```

ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mainjava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.awesomedevelop.recyclerview/com.awesomedevelop.recyclerview.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что у тебя асинхронный запрос. `onResponse` вызывается после загрузки информации, а `System.out.println(pathPoster)` вызывается до загрузки, судя по твоему коду. То есть, когда информация еще не успела загрузиться из сети. А падает потому что строка в которую ты не записал еще данные по-умолчанию `null`.

Либо делай синхронный запрос, либо все действия после загрузки выполняй в `onResponse`.

Если переделаешь на синхронный запрос, учти, что синхронные запросы в сеть, нельзя делать в `Ui` потоке приложения.

http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего работать через Singleton-класс, к которому можно будет обратиться и из UI-потока и из асинхронного ответа

Comment: runOnUiThread есть метод у активности. А вообще асинхронный ответ всегда в Потоке Ui, так что в этом нет необходимости.